# How jQuery datatable attribute columnDefs work's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have confusion on `jQuery Datatables`, I saw few code where `datatables use columndefs`, I don't understand `columndefs` attributes [targets] and [orderable]
actually what they do.

Here is a sample code.

```
"columnDefs":[  
  {  
    "targets":[0, 3, 4],  
    "orderable":false,  
  },  
],
```

Comment: Consult the official documentation. https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, ordering is disabled for columns with indexes 0,3 and 4